# Wordpress Multisite: an official and definitive way to enable https ? (http to https)

Tags: multisite

the actually version of Wordpress is 4.7.3 and if you have Multisite option enable and the sites are on http you can't change the permalink for use https.

And this is incredible.

So, there is a way for do that without problem ?

Using htaccess mod rewrite haven't sense.
The plugin Wordpress Multisite Domain Mapping doesn't work (last update was 2 year ago).

Comment: Please explain, what do you mean by: `Using htaccess mod rewrite haven't sense`?

Comment: Because the plugin that generate the XML Sitemap will generate URL in http and not in https.

Comment: Your question makes no reference to the sitemap. If you're having trouble with the plugin you're using to generate sitemaps, you should check with the plugin maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just finished setting up https on a multisite here - https://wpexplorer-themes.com/ - personally we are using CloudFlare so we just create a new page rule inside our dashboard to redirect traffic. The way to set things up depends on your server for example on WPEngine when you setup your SSL there is a button in the WPE dashboard to force HTTPS on the site and if you don't use that and use a .htaccess tweak instead you could end up in an endless loop. I highly recommend asking your host or consulting your hosting company's documentation to see what the best way is.

Comment: And for the sitemap how you resolve this ?

Comment: That's a good question, what plugin are you using? A well coded plugin should be using core functions so they should be returning the correct URL's - but you may have to "re-build" the sitemap if there is a setting to do so.